# Fuchsian Generators vs Schottky Generators

Tags: complex-geometry, riemann-surfaces, hyperbolic-geometry

Let $\Sigma_{g,n}$ be a closed genus $g$ Riemann surface with $n$ marked points. $\Sigma_{g,n}$ has Fuchsian as well as Schottky uniformization. Fuchsian uniformization is done by a Fuchsian group and Schottky uniformization is done by a Schottky group. Then:

- What is the number of generators of the Fuchsian group in terms of $g$ and $n$?
- What is the number of generators of the Schottky group in terms of $g$ and $n$?
- Let $\{\gamma_a^F\}$ be a set of Fuchsian generators and $\{\gamma_a^S\}$ be a set of Schottky generators. How can these two sets be related to each other? In other words, given $\{\gamma_a^F\}$, how can one construct $\{\gamma_a^S\}$ or given $\{\gamma_a^F\}$, how can one construct $\{\gamma_a^S\}$? Is there any systematic way?

Comment: You cannot say "the set" about generators, they are not unique. Also, do you mean "free generators"? Otherwise even the number is not well defined.

Comment: Dear @MoisheCohen , You are right! I changed it. 
Yes, I mean 'free generators'. A good reference on the subject would be very helpful too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question seems to be still ill-defined. First of all, while there is a standard definition of Schottky uniformization for compact surfaces, there does not seem to be one for punctured surfaces. Here is an ad-hoc definition. In particular, I see no meaningful way to define it when the number of punctures is odd. Therefore, I will assume from now on that $n=2p$ is even. I will also assume that either $g> 1$, or $g=1$ and $n\ge 2$, or $g=0$ and $n\ge 4$.

**Definition.** A Schottky-type group of type $(g,p)$ is a free discrete subgroup $G$ of $PSL(2, {\mathbb C})$ which is free on $g+p$ generators, where $g$ of the free generators (namely $A_1,...,A_g$) are loxodromic and $p$ generators (namely $C_1,...,C_p$) are parabolic, and the limit set of $G$ is homeomorphic to a Cantor set.

One can show that if $\Omega$ is the domain of discontinuity of $G$ then the quotient surface $\Omega/G$ has genus $g$ and $2p$ punctures. 
This answers your question 2.

For question 1, you do not need the requirement that $n$ is even. You have to specify what a "Fuchsian generating set" is. Again, for closed surfaces, one can say that this is a **standard** generating set of the compact surface of genus $g$, equivalently, any generating set consisting of $2g$ elements. When you allow $n>0$ punctures, I guess, you can say that this is a set of free generators $a_1,b_1,...,a_g, b_g, c_1,...,c_{n-1}$ consisting of $2g+(n-1)$ elements such that
$$
c_1\ldots c_{n-1} c_n \prod_{i=1}^g [a_i,b_i]  = 1,
$$
where each $c_i$ is represented by a loop going once around the $i$-th puncture (in the positive direction with respect to the orientation of the surface).

As for your question 3, my guess is that the relation is given by a homomorphism $b_k\to 1$, $a_j\to A_j$, $c_{i} c_{p+i} \to C_i$ for each $i, j, k$.

As for references, maybe [this paper](http://mathlab.snu.ac.kr/~top/articles/zindinova.pdf) and references therein would be useful. (I got it by googling.) Another possible references is the book "Kleinian Groups" by B.Maskit.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! In physics literature, more specifically old string theory literature, the people freely talk about Schottky uniformization of punctured surfaces without any reference. My questions or a proper modification of them seem to be standard but I couldn't find any good literature that deals with them. One of the references in the paper you mentioned is about extended Schottky groups. It seems that these groups uniformize Riemann surfaces with punctures. It has the same limitation that it is only applicable to surfaces with an even number of punctures.